# Present actual data in SSRS Pie Chart - not in Percentage

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, pie-chart, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a pie chart and I don't want to display percentages, but the whole number value from the source.

I want the chart to display the actual numbers, and not a percentage, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to achieve, just follow these simple steps:

> 1. On the design surface, right-click on the pie and select *Show Data
>      Labels*. The data labels should appear within each slice on the pie
>      chart.
> 2. On the design surface, right-click on the labels and select *Series
>      Label Properties*. The Series Label Properties dialog box appears.
> 3. In the S*eries Label Properties*, in the *General* tab. You must enter the *Label data* you wish to be displayed. This can be done by
>      clicking the *Expression* button (***fx***) and defining
>      which column's data you wish to display.
>      For example: `=Sum(Fields!MyColumn.Value)`

If you have any trouble, feel free to respond and perhaps add some more information about your DataSource.